# Async waiting for another request without blocking

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have a websocket application which is an OWIN middleware. When a requests comes in, a new instance of the websocket handler is started, which then waits for icoming messages in a loop like this:

```
var buffer = new byte[1024*64];
Tuple<ArraySegment<byte>, WebSocketMessageType> received;
do
{
    received = await _webSocket.ReceiveMessage(buffer, _cancellationToken.Token);
    if (received.Item1.Count > 0 && someConditionForCallingDoSomething)
    {
        await DoSomething(received.Item1);
    }
    else if(isAnswer)
    {
        QueueAnswer(received.Item1);
    }
} while (received.Item2 != WebSocketMessageType.Close);
```

The Task returned from `_webSocket.ReceiveMessage` will complete when data is available.

`DoSomething` processes its data and then sends something via the websocket connection. Then it should wait for a message via the websocket connection. After processing this message, it should do some work and return (the task).
Maybe this little diagram explains it somhow easier:

```
_______________
| DoSomething |
|-------------|
|    Work  ---------> Send WS message
|             |
|     ??      |
|             |
|  More Work <------- Receive WS message
|   |         |
|   V         |
|  return;    |
|_____________|

Do some work with the data
          |
          V
     Send a message
          |
          V
   Wait for an answer
          |
          V
    Process answer
          |
          V
        finish
```

What I have tried to wait for an answer:

```
var answerCancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
answerCancel.CancelAfter(30 * 1000);

var answer = await Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        string tmpAnswer = null;

        while (!_concurrentAnswerDict.TryGetValue(someKey, out tmpAnswer)) {
            await Task.Delay(150, answerCancel.Token);
        }

        return tmpAnswer;
    }, answerCancel.Token);
```

But this seems to block until the task is cancelled. When I debug the program, I see the call of `QueueAnswer` after 30 seconds. I thought, `Task.Run` will run the function in a new thread, but it seems like it does not. From the view that `Task.Run` is blocking, it seems logical to me that it does not work, because I await the execution of `DoSomething`, therefore receiving new messages will be blocked too.

My question is: How do I implement a behaviour like this? How do I make `DoSomething` waiting for another websocket message, before completing?

Thank you in advance for every hint

Lukas

Comment: It's not really clear where that last snippet of code comes in. Is that `DoSomething`? It would be useful if you could provide a [mcve] rather than just bits and pieces.

Comment: `await Task.Run(...)` is usually a warning sign of some form of misunderstanding. You're running code on a perfectly usable thread. You're going to push work into a new Task and then *give up* the thread you *were* using, until the new `Task` has completed.

Comment: `How do I make DoSomething waiting for another websocket message, before completing?` Is the message it's waiting for always the next message? If so, `DoSomething` can just call `_webSocket.ReceiveMessage`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it was my attempt to solve the problem in `DoSomething`. I'll provide a mcve in a few minutes, it takes some time because there's much OWIN and websocket stuff happening...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever but won't running the loop in the original thread block reading new messages, too?

Comment: @StephenCleary unfortunately it's not guaranteed that the answer ist the next incoming message. Calling `ReceiveMessage` from the loop and queueing all irrelevant messages for later processing can work, but it's pretty ugly I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I recommend using SignalR, since they handle a lot of this hard stuff for you. But if you want to do it yourself, read on...

Also, I'm assuming that "do work" and "answer" messages can arrive on the same web socket in any order, and that you're using `_concurrentAnswerDict` to coordinate an outgoing "question" message from `DoSomething` with incoming "answer" messages.

In that case, you're going to need a "websocket reader" task that is independent of `DoSomething`; you can't have your reader `await` `DoSomething` because that will prevent reading answers. I think that's the main problem you're having.

This is one of the rare cases where it may be acceptable to *not* `await` a task. Assuming `DoSomething` will catch its own exceptions and handle logging and whatnot, then we can treat it as an independent "main" and ignore the task it returns:

```
var buffer = new byte[1024*64];
Tuple<ArraySegment<byte>, WebSocketMessageType> received;
do
{
  received = await _webSocket.ReceiveMessage(buffer, _cancellationToken.Token);
  if (received.Item1.Count > 0 && someConditionForCallingDoSomething)
  {
    var _ = DoSomething(received.Item1);
  }
  else if(isAnswer)
  {
    QueueAnswer(received.Item1);
  }
} while (received.Item2 != WebSocketMessageType.Close);
```

And that should allow `QueueAnswer` to run while `DoSomething` is not yet completed.

> I thought, Task.Run will run the function in a new thread, but it seems like it does not. From the view that Task.Run is blocking, it seems logical to me that it does not work, because I await the execution of DoSomething, therefore receiving new messages will be blocked too.

`Task.Run` *is* running in another thread. But `DoSomething` is (asynchronously) waiting for it to complete, and the reading loop is (asynchronously) waiting for `DoSomething` to complete before it reads the next message.

Other notes:

```
while (!_concurrentAnswerDict.TryGetValue(someKey, out tmpAnswer)) {
  await Task.Delay(150, answerCancel.Token);
}
```

This seems quite odd to me. I would recommend using a dictionary of keys to `TaskCompletionSource<Answer>` instead of `Answer`. Then, `QueueAnswer` would call `TaskCompletionSource<Answer>.SetResult`, and this code would just await `TaskCompletionSource<Answer>.Task` (along with `Task.Delay` if a timeout is desired).

Comment: Omitting the await made it work. Thank you for the detailed answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use signal r and receive the response on the client side.
Or better yet send the request in the client side and receive it on the client side.

Using await will block as you are sending a request to the server and waits for a response.